# Live data not populating

Tags: telerik, rotator

I am trying to do live updation based the following demo.
https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/rotator/examples/livexml/defaultcs.aspx.But after updating the xml how the radrotator showing the updated value?.I am getting the updated value.How it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate a postback or an Ajax request and rebind the RadRotator in order to display the updated data in the control.